# Homogeneity of a function within a region

Tags: plotting, cluster-analysis

I have 2 functions;

funtion 1:

```
ctr = {(Exp[Pi*0.5] + 1)/2, 0};
radius = (Exp[Pi*0.5] - 1)/2;
pp = PolarPlot[
  Evaluate@Table[Exp[(t + 2*Pi*i/120)*0.5], {i, 1, 120}], {t, -Pi, 
   Pi}, RegionFunction -> (Norm[{#, #2} - ctr] <= radius &)]
Total[ArcLength /@ Cases[pp, _Line, All]]
```

[image: spiral]

and function 2:

```
ctr = {(Exp[Pi*0.5] - 1)/2, 0};
radius = (Exp[Pi*0.5] - 1)/2;
pp2 = ParametricPlot[
  Evaluate[Table[{t, t (Tan[2 j Pi / 120])}, {j, 1, 60}]], {t, -5, 5},
   RegionFunction -> (Norm[{#, #2} - ctr] <= radius &), 
  PlotRange -> All]
Total[ArcLength /@ Cases[pp2, _Line, All]]
```

[image: Line]

I want to show that function 1 is distributed within the circle more homogeneously than function 2 as it is inferred by the graphs. It is clearly seen that function 1 is more homogeneous but I need to support it by the data. How can I show it in mathematica?

Maybe, the area between the lines in the intersection circle give me what I want as below:

[image: gradient]

I can show that the maximum missing spaces between the lines are less in function 1.

Comment: We need a definition of what you mean by homogeneous. Perhaps the gradient is constant or the gradient is approximately constant compared to...?

Comment: @Hugh Yes, actually change in the gradient is a good point to prove homogenity. I will edit the question.

Comment: @Hugh Do you think the areas between the lines may help me with my purpose? I edited the question.

Comment: Best would be to get an expression for the function within the region. Then take its gradient. Can you give the expression for the function? It is not clear to me why you are representing your function as a set of lines.

Comment: Because it will pass the circle discretely. The spiral rotates around the z axis by 3 degrees at a time. The function is in polar r=e^((θ+θr)*0.5) θ: -Pi to Pi and θr: 0 to 2Pi. Intersection circle is: {(Exp[Pi*0.5] + 1)/2, 0} with radius (Exp[Pi*0.5] - 1)/2 in the first function.

Comment: We need more clarity in what you are doing. What you call your first function seems to be a list of trajectories plotted within a circular region. This is not a function but a list of trajectories. A function would have the form  f[r,theta] = ...